# How to create a tree structure with matching parent ID´s via http request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, http

I'm setting up a tree view from an JSON array I get from an HTTP request.
Each object in the array has a parent ID that links to the parent object. I need to create a tree view out of this array logic.

The loop should be run multiple times till the parent ID is 0. Its possible to have multiple levels.

My JSON Array looks like this. (based on console.log(level1['_source']);)

```
1: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "31", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {
ID: "66"
content: "Berlin"
indexID: "9"
parentID: "26"
}, …}
2: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "26", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {
ID: "26"
content: "Germany"
indexID: "9"
parentID: "0"
}, …}
3: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "272", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {…}, …}
4: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "392", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {…}, …}
5: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "33", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {…}, …}
6: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "64", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {…}, …}
7: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "27", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {…}, …}
8: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "65", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {…}, …}
9: {_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "438", _score: 1.4142135, _so
```

It should be build like this->

1. Germany

   - Berlin
   - Kreuzberg
   - München
2. France

   - Paris

this is my POST http request.

```
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: body,
    timeout: 4000
 }).then(function (result) {
      $scope.doc = result.data.hits.hits;
      $scope.doc.forEach(level1 => {
        // TODO in level1['_source'] are all elements. SO what to do next ?
        console.log(level1['_source']);
      });

 }, function (error) {
    errorCallback(error);
 });
```

I'am thinking about to count the parentID from 0,1,2,3,4,5... 
and store each group of identical id´s in a new array inside the next array.

If Germany has the ID 26 and parentID = 0, it's the first level.
If Berlin, Munich, Hamburg has the parentID = 26, it's the second level inside of Germany... and so on so on.

I'm not sure what's the best logic here.

Comment: Does `$scope.doc instanceof Array` evaluate as `true`? It looks like an Object in which case it doesn't have a `forEach` method.

Comment: why do you create a treeview on client side? why don't you create on server side? I think you keep data on database and there are several ways to keep and create treeview data on database engines.

Comment: I Didnt have access on server side. So the only solution is to loop trough each element and sort it into a tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So building a tree out of flat array.. let's try this:

```
var items = [{_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "31", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {
ID: "66",
content: "Berlin",
indexID: "9",
parentID: "26"
}},
{
_index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "26", _score: 1.4142135, _source: {
ID: "26",
content: "Germany",
indexID: "9",
parentID: "0"
}}]

const tree = {}

function buildTree(treeObject, sourceArray, level)
{
    const nodes = sourceArray.filter(item => item._source.parentID == level)

  for (const node of nodes)
  {
    const id = node._source.ID
    treeObject[id] = node

    buildTree(treeObject[id], sourceArray, id)
  }
}

buildTree(tree, items, 0)

console.log(tree)
```

BTW: this question just happen to occur in `angularjs`... the mechanism itself is pure JS

### Edit:

To make `buildTree` function suitable to tree-based components, change functions as followed:

- change `tree` object to array
- for each node -> initialize `children` member as empty array
- send the `children` array to the recursive function call

**In short:**

```
const tree = []

function buildTree(treeObject, sourceArray, level)
{
    const nodes = sourceArray.filter(item => item._source.parentID == level)

  for (const node of nodes)
  {
    const id = node._source.ID

    node.children = []

    buildTree(node.children, sourceArray, id)

    treeObject.push(node)
  }
}

buildTree(tree, items, 0)

console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Hi ymz, this works perfect. Thank you very much!!! This question is marked as AngularJS because I'm not sure how to archive a perfect output on the front-end with the JSON object tree. Now I have the perfect JSON but what do i need to create it perfectly in the front-end. Nested ng-repeats with <ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>......

Comment: yeah.. it is a tricky one (should clone and manipulate the code in `buildTree` function)... maybe you should update your question

Comment: iam using angular-tree-control module right now. Ive updatet my question so as you can see it needs a JSON structure that looks like the example above.